# Feedback on Euclidean Algorithm: $gcd(277, 301)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, solution-verification

Ans:

$301 =277 \cdot 1 + 24$

$277 =24 \cdot 11 + 13$

$24 = 13 \cdot 1 + 11$

$13 = 11 \cdot 1 + 2$

$11 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1$

$2 = 1 \cdot 2 + 0$

Is this correct?

Comment: So what's the answer?

Answer (score 2):

**GCD(277,301):**

- $301 - (277 \times 1) = 24$
- $277 - (24 \times 11) = 13$
- $24 - (13 \times 1) = 11$
- $13 - (11 \times 1) = 2$
- $11 - (2 \times 5) = 1$
- $2 - (1 \times 2) = 0$

Thus the result is $\mbox{GCD}(277, 301) = 1$.

Expressed differently, we have:

- Divisors of $277: 1, 277~$ (that is, a prime)
- Divisors of $301: 1, 7, 43, 301$

What is the greatest common divisor between the two? Answer $ = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me, though it would probably help to put each division on a new line, just as far as readability goes.